# There is no row at position 0 error in datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net

With below code, I get error as

> There is no row at position 0.

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    DataTable dtExcel = new DataTable();
    dtExcel.Clear();

    if (Convert.ToInt32(dtExcel.Rows[0]["Mkey"]) > 0) // here is the error
    {
      Hid_Mode.Value = "M";
      hid_mkey.Value = dtExcel.Rows[0]["Mkey"].ToString();
    }
    else
    {
      Hid_Mode.Value = "A";
      hid_mkey.Value = "0";
    }
```

Comment: What else you expect after calling `dtExcel.Clear()`?

Comment: That's because you've cleared the datatable at `dtExcel.Clear();`

Comment: @Shaharyar: i want to check whether there is data in table or not

Comment: @AlexJolig: no its not because of that

Comment: You are trying to convert a row which doesn't exist anymore after using `dtExcel.Clear();`. How's is not because of that?

Comment: @AlexJolig: i tried removing  `dtExcel.Clear();` still i am getting the same error, yes there is no row in the table, so how to handle that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change you code like this:

```
DataTable dtExcel = new DataTable();
dtExcel.Clear();

if (dtExcel.Rows.Count > 0) //Here's the change
{
  Hid_Mode.Value = "M";
  hid_mkey.Value = dtExcel.Rows[0]["Mkey"].ToString();
}
else
{
  Hid_Mode.Value = "A";
  hid_mkey.Value = "0";
}
```

Comment: but when it has some records in the table, it should go into the `IF` condition and it is not going

Comment: @coder That's what this code does. If it doesn't go to if, certainly your datatable is empty.

Comment: how can it be empty, there are records in the datatable

Comment: my excel data is not coming into the datatable, what to do for that

Comment: @coder I suggest you ask a new question sharing your code about inserting excel data into  the database and explain the issue.